# Displaying progress of fetching in MailKit

Tags: fetch, mailkit

When I have a lot of messages in mailbox client.Inbox.Fetch() method last a long time and users think that program is not responding. Can I display progress of fetched messages?

```
IList<IMessageSummary> allMailList = client.Inbox.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId, cancellationToken);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can connect to the `ImapFolder.MessageSummaryFetched` event and, based on the number of times that's been called compared to the number of messages you are fetching summary information for, you can provide some progress reporting.